# Amsterdam: How to get from the Airport to the Hard Rock Cafe by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, amsterdam, ams

What's the fastest and cheapest way to get from the Schiphol Airport to the Hard Rock Cafe by public transport?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided you would like to go to the Hardrock Cafe in Amsterdam: take the train from Schiphol Airport to Amsterdam Central station (15 minutes or so; you can plan details on [ns.nl](http://www.ns.nl)).

From Amsterdam Central Station take a tram number 1, 2 or 5 and get out on [Leidseplein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidseplein) (again, some 15 minutes).
[Walk from there](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Leidseplein&daddr=Hard+Rock+Cafe+Amsterdam&hl=en&sll=52.362576,4.884957&sspn=0.005399,0.016512&geocode=FdsBHwMdJ4FKACmZksbt6AnGRzF7sppXNsFJeg%3BFQj7HgMdDoJKACHadyTEMZZshw&vpsrc=0&dirflg=w&mra=ltm&t=m&z=18) (5 minutes or less)

Comment: Or walk there in approximately 30m, while sightseeing central Amsterdam: [route](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=Amsterdam+Central+Station,+Stationsplein,+Binnenstad,+Amsterdam,+The+Netherlands&daddr=Hard+Rock+Cafe,+Max+Euweplein,+Amsterdam,+The+Netherlands&hl=en&geocode=Fdc6HwMdUMZKACFPH3UZrl_HmCk57nJztwnGRzFrWhNBAKMjpw%3BFQj7HgMdDoJKACHadyTEMZZshw&aq=0&sll=52.37035,4.886665&sspn=0.025888,0.052314&vpsrc=0&dirflg=w&mra=ltm&ie=UTF8&ll=52.370176,4.891105&spn=0.025888,0.052314&t=h&z=15)

Comment: Wouldn't qualify as 'fastest', I think, but it is an option.

Answer (score 7):

### Option 1

Take the train Schiphol Airport -> Amsterdam Central Station

On weekdays take tram number 5 (direction: A'veen Binnenhof). This tram goes every 15 minutes.

Weekend you can take tram number 1 or 2:

- Tram 1 (to Osdorp De Aker)
- Tram 2 (to Nieuw Sloten)

For all trams, you need to get out on Leidseplein. From there it's a small 5 minute walk.

Tram price is around 1,20 euro

### Option 2

There is also a bus (197 to Amsterdam) which goes from Schiphol to Leidseplein. This trip will take around 35 minutes and will cost about 3 euro.

This bus goes every 15 minutes.

Comment: Unless this has changed recently (and the [GVB website](http://www.gvb.nl/reisinformatie/plattegronden/Pages/Tram-en-metronet.aspx) doesn't indicate this), lines 1, 2 and 5 all go through Leidseplein.

Comment: I just checked at 9292ov.nl and they still give this as an option. Both weekdays and weekend.

Answer (score 3):

[Google maps directions](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Schiphol%20Airport,%20Schiphol,%20The%20Netherlands&daddr=Max%20Euweplein%2057-%2061,%201017%20MA%20Amsterdam,%20Nederland%20%28Hard%20Rock%20Cafe%29&hl=en&ll=52.344149,4.831066&spn=0.080436,0.222988&sll=52.33597,4.81617&sspn=0.080451,0.222988&geocode=FZ8wHgMdJK5IACkdThFbKOHFRzHbtM1Jee19Cw;FQj7HgMdDoJKACHadyTEMZZshw&vpsrc=0&dirflg=r&ttype=now&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&mra=ltm&t=m&z=13&start=0) has four possible options for you to pick.

If you zoom enough in the destination you will see the Hard Rock Cafe

Answer (score 2):

Whether by bus, tram or train, it's not going to take you much longer than 25-30 minutes, assuming you're going during opening hours.

The 300 or 310 bus will take you into town to Schipol Noord, in 7 minutes.  From there, the 197 towards Marnixstraat takes 22 min, and at the 9th stop (Leidseplein) you're a 3 min walk from the cafe - 250m away.

If you prefer train and tram, the sprinter train will take you into Leylaan station in 6 minutes, from where (1 min walk) you can take the #1 tram towards the Centraal Station (12 min), and at Stadhouderskade you can get off and walk to the cafe - 300m away.

(The cafe's address is Max Euweplein 57- 61, 1017 MA Amsterdam)